# Perl Net::Pcap hex dump packet session

Tags: perl, packet, hexdump

I have the following information below being produced by the [`Net::Pcap`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::Pcap) module to print the payload of the packets of interest within a capture.

The data below is the excerpt of a Windows executable file being captured within Perl.

I would like to be able to capture all of the hex data output into one file or variable to assess the session data of the file download while retaining the integrity of the hex dump.

The problem I am having is for each packet being produced for the download of the file it obviously produces a hex dump output. This is easily seen by the output below by the string "Payload" I print per packet/hex dump output.

I want to tie all relevant data together for a given file download session. How can I do this in Perl?

```
Payload:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Jun 2012 02:31:32 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Sat, 10 Dec 2011 13:38:37 GMT
ETag: "dc44da-4d000-4b3bd04c7a2f1"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 315392
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/x-msdos-program

MZ<90>^@^C^@^@^@^D^@^@^@<FF><FF>^@^@<B8>^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<F8>^@^@^@^N^_<BA>^N^@<B4> <CD>!<B8>^AL<CD>!This program cannot be run in DOS mode.^M
$^@^@^@^@^@^@^@4^TGmpu)>pu)>pu)>c}@>ru)>uyI>ru)>uy&>ku)>c}t>ru)><F3>}t>uu)>pu(>
u)>uyv><DA>u)><9C>~w>qu)>uys>qu)>Richpu)>^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@PE^@^@L^A^D^@^_R<E3>N^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<E0>^@^O^A^K^A^G
^@<80>^C^@^@<90>^A^@^@^@^@^@g^F^C^@^@^P^@^@^@<90>^C^@^@^@@^@^@^P^@^@^@^P^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^E^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^C^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<A8><91>^D^@P^@^@^@^@^@^E^@<C8>^T^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@<91>^D^@H^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@<90>^C^@<D0>^A^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@.text^@^@^@As^C^@^@^P^@^@^@<80>^C^@^@^P^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ ^@^@`.rdata^@^@<C2>^K^A^@^@<90>^C^@^@^P^A^@^@<90>^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@@.data^@^@^@D]^@^@^@<A0>^D^@^@^P^@^@^@<A0>^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@<C0>.rsrc^@^@^@<C8>^T^@^@^@^@^E^@^@ ^@^@^@<B0>^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@@^@^@@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Payload:^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
```

Thank you Borodin for the suggestion. However, I don't know how to use this module correctly and it is apparent as I am still getting the same output. Here is the snippet of code I am using with this module and the printed hex. As you can see the printed hex is not tied together as one hex output but two separate for the given TCP stream for which I want to tie together.

```
my $user_data;
my $header;
my $packet;    
my $err ='';
my $pcap = Net::Pcap::open_offline("./pcap", \$err) or die "can't open ./pcap...$err\n";
Net::Pcap::loop($pcap, -1, \&process_pkt, '');
Net::Pcap::Reassemble::loop($pcap, -1, \&rend_callback, '');
Net::Pcap::close($pcap);

my $ip;
my $tcp;
my $payload;
sub process_pkt   
{
my ($user_data,$header, $packet) = @_;
$ip = NetPacket::IP->decode(eth_strip($packet));
$tcp = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip->{data});
$payload = $tcp->{data};

my $hexPayload = hexdump(data => $payload, start_position => 0) if length $payload;
print "Hex Payload:". $hexPayload;
}
```

#### Print output, Hex Payload:

```
0x0000 : 47 45 54 20 2F 6D 61 63 2F 5F 62 61 73 65 5F 76 : GET./mac/_base_v
0x0010 : 31 2F 73 63 72 69 70 74 2F 6A 71 75 65 72 79 2D : 1/script/jquery- 
0x0020 : 31 2E 36 2E 31 2E 6A 73 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E : 1.6.1.js.HTTP/1. 
0x0030 : 31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : 1..Host:.www.mic 
0x0040 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 : rosoft.com..User 
0x0050 : 2D 41 67 65 6E 74 3A 20 4D 6F 7A 69 6C 6C 61 2F : -Agent:.Mozilla/ 
0x0060 : 35 2E 30 20 28 4D 61 63 69 6E 74 6F 73 68 3B 20 : 5.0.(Macintosh;. 
0x0070 : 49 6E 74 65 6C 20 4D 61 63 20 4F 53 20 58 20 31 : Intel.Mac.OS.X.1 
0x0080 : 30 2E 36 3B 20 72 76 3A 31 33 2E 30 29 20 47 65 : 0.6;.rv:13.0).Ge 
0x0090 : 63 6B 6F 2F 32 30 31 30 30 31 30 31 20 46 69 72 : cko/20100101.Fir 
0x00A0 : 65 66 6F 78 2F 31 33 2E 30 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : efox/13.0..Accep 
0x00B0 : 74 3A 20 2A 2F 2A 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D 4C : t:.*/*..Accept-L 
0x00C0 : 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3A 20 65 6E 2D 75 73 2C 65 : anguage:.en-us,e 
0x00D0 : 6E 3B 71 3D 30 2E 35 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D : n;q=0.5..Accept- 
0x00E0 : 45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 2C 20 : Encoding:.gzip,. 
0x00F0 : 64 65 66 6C 61 74 65 0D 0A 52 65 66 65 72 65 72 : deflate..Referer 
0x0100 : 3A 20 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : :.http://www.mic 
0x0110 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 6D 61 63 2F 72 : rosoft.com/mac/r 
0x0120 : 65 6D 6F 74 65 2D 64 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 2D 63 6C : emote-desktop-cl 
0x0130 : 69 65 6E 74 0D 0A 44 4E 54 3A 20 31 0D 0A 43 6F : ient..DNT:.1..Co 
0x0140 : 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65 70 2D 61 : nnection:.keep-a 
0x0150 : 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 :
```

#### live Hex Payload

```
0x0000 : 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D : HTTP/1.1.200.OK. 
0x0010 : 0A 43 61 63 68 65 2D 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 3A 20 : .Cache-Control:. 
0x0020 : 6D 61 78 2D 61 67 65 3D 39 30 30 0D 0A 43 6F 6E : max-age=900..Con 
0x0030 : 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69 : tent-Type:.appli 
0x0040 : 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 78 2D 6A 61 76 61 73 63 72 : cation/x-javascr 
0x0050 : 69 70 74 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 45 6E 63 : ipt..Content-Enc 
0x0060 : 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 0D 0A 4C 61 73 : oding:.gzip..Las 
0x0070 : 74 2D 4D 6F 64 69 66 69 65 64 3A 20 57 65 64 2C : t-Modified:.Wed, 
0x0080 : 20 30 38 20 4A 75 6E 20 32 30 31 31 20 31 38 3A : .08.Jun.2011.18: 
0x0090 : 34 35 3A 34 39 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : 45:49.GMT..Accep
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`Net::Pcap::Reassemble`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aPcap%3a%3aReassemble)

> This module performs reassembly of fragmented datagrams in libpcap
>   packet capture data returned by the Net::Pcap loop() function

Comment: Hi Borodin I have updated the question per trying your suggestion and provided a snippet of the code and the output I am getting using the Reassemble module.  It isn't working correclty and it is apparently due to the fact that I am not familiar with using this module.  Can you please assist?  Thx